# Phusion Passenger PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp doesn't seem to work

Tags: passenger

I have many Ruby on Rails apps on a Apache Server on a Ubuntu Server.
I set the following in /etc/apache2.conf.

PassengerMaxInstancesPerApp 2

However, when I check 'passenger-status', I find the following.

```
/home/ssk/public/myapp#default:
  App root: /home/ssk/public/myapp
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 17270   Sessions: 0       Processed: 537     Uptime: 1h 30m 16s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 92M     Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 20175   Sessions: 0       Processed: 484     Uptime: 59m 9s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 87M     Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 20244   Sessions: 0       Processed: 535     Uptime: 58m 23s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 87M     Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 20256   Sessions: 0       Processed: 480     Uptime: 58m 20s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 88M     Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 20278   Sessions: 1       Processed: 511     Uptime: 58m 5s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 87M     Last used: 0s ago
  * PID: 21024   Sessions: 0       Processed: 319     Uptime: 49m 6s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 91M     Last used: 23s ago
  * PID: 25326   Sessions: 0       Processed: 121     Uptime: 5m 30s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 86M     Last used: 23s ago

/home/kuamerica/public/myapp2#default:
  App root: /home/kuamerica/public/myapp2
  Requests in queue: 0
  * PID: 23253   Sessions: 0       Processed: 210     Uptime: 31m 10s
    CPU: 0%      Memory  : 94M     Last used: 2s ago
```

As you can see, there are 7 instances for an app. Why doesn't it work as expected?

For your information, myapp is not Rack but Classic Rails (2.3).

Thanks.

Sam